# Allow only HTTP/HTTPS comunication with Agitum Outpost Security Suite Free

Tags: firewall, http, port, https, network-protocols

Hi I use Agitum Outpost Security Suite Free and I would like allow only HTTP(80) a HTTPS(443) protocols for IN/OUT and also allow local ports for Oracle database, etc.

I try use Network Rules -> System Wizard Rules and add this rules:

```
Where the protocol is TCP
Block

Where the protocol is UDP
Block

Where the Protocol is TCP
    and Local Port is HTTP
 Allow It 

Where the Protocol is TCP
    and Remote Port is HTTP
 Allow It 


Where the Protocol is TCP
    and Local Port is HTTPS
 Allow It 


Where the Protocol is TCP
    and Remote Port is HTTPS
 Allow It
```

But now I can use web browser and any application which using HTTP. What I did bad?

How can I block all ports and allow only HTTP/HTTPS for IN/OUT.